# In R, how do I save a data.tree plot to a file?

Tags: r, image, plot, tree, save

I'm unable to save a plot generated by the `plot.Node` function in `data.tree`. I've tried the following:

```
### Create tree object and plot it
data(acme);
plot(acme);
```

This works fine, showing the plot, as one would expect.

```
### Try saving it as png
png(filename='file.png', type='cairo-png');
plot(acme);
dev.off();
```

This creates an empty file. `ggsave` does the same. Apparantly, `plot.Node` uses `DiagrammeR` under the hood, so I looked into that package. It has a function to export graphs:

```
export_graph(acme, file_name="file.png");
```

This gives the error:

```
Error in file.exists(diagram) : invalid 'file' argument
```

When I transform to GraphViz first, I get a different error:

```
export_graph(ToGraphViz(acme), file_name="file.png");

Error in graph$dot_code : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Clearly, exporting to GraphViz doesn't quite export to what DiagrammeR expects.

I'm in RStudio and so could in theory just save the plot using the GUI, but I need this for in a script.

Apparently, `plot.Node` doesn't actually *plot* anything - instead it seems to generate html/js. Does this mean that that result cannot be stored as a graphic? Or is there some export/conversion function somewhere that I'm completely missing? it certainly feels like I'm missing something obvious - I assume the need to store plotted `data.tree`s as images is quite common. But I have no idea which potential solutions I can still explore.

I'd be very grateful for any pointers anybody has!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As sebastian-c suggested, things work now a bit differently than suggested by Matherion, as of R 3.3.3 with data.tree 0.7.0 and DiagrammeR 0.9.0

Pre-requisite: DiagrmmeRsvg and dependencies need to be installed. Depending on your OS, for this to work you might have to install V8. For example on ubuntu:

```
apt-get install libv8-3.14-delibv8-3.14-dev
```

And then in R:

```
install.packages("DiagrammeRsvg")
```

On Windows, I didn't have to install anything (maybe because Chrome is installed?).

Once DiagrammeRsvg is available, run:

```
library(data.tree)
data(acme)
library(DiagrammeR)
export_graph(ToDiagrammeRGraph(acme), "export.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer, at least, partially. There exists a package dedicated to exporting GraphViz diagrams to SVG: [DiagrammeRsvg](https://rdrr.io/cran/DiagrammeRsvg/man/export_svg.html).

So this works:

```
treeAsSVG <- export_svg(grViz(ToGraphViz(acme)));
writeLines(treeAsSVG, "filename.svg"));
```

The grViz is necessary to actually convert the `ToGRaphViz` output to something that can be interpreted by `export_svg`. I'm still not really sure (yet) what all goes on under the hood - for example, this does *not* work:

```
export_graph(grViz(ToGraphViz(acme)), file_name="filename.svg");
```

But, if anybody else has a similar problem and stumbles upon this question, perhaps this partial answer can help them to at least export something that can then be integrated in e.g. html pages.

Comment: Where does the `ToGraphViz` function come from?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with newer versions of the package. I used `treeAsSVG <- export_svg(render_graph(ToDiagrammeRGraph(acme)))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

By converting acme with as.phylo() it works, but it looks a little boring:

```
plot(as.phylo(acme),
     show.node.label=TRUE,
     node.pos=2,
     no.margin=TRUE
     )
# adding edge labels
edgelabels(as.vector(acme$Get("cost"))[-1],
           adj = c(0,-0.5),
           frame = "none")
```

[solution with as.phylo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uBrK.png)

I also tried as.igraph. However, the nodes overlap and it looks even less pretty:

```
plot(0, type="n", ann=FALSE, axes=FALSE, 
 xlim=extendrange(ig[,1]), 
 ylim=extendrange(ig[,2]))
plot(ig,
 layout=layout_as_tree(ig,root=1),
 vertex.shape="rectangle",
 vertex.size=(strwidth(V(ig)$name) + strwidth("oo")) * 100,
 #vertex.size2=strheight("I") * 2 * 100,
 edge.label=acme$Get("p",traversal = "level")[-1]
)
```

[solution with as.igraph()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZyHW.png)